# ImportError: No module named mysql.connector when using cron-jb

Tags: python, cron

on my hosting provider, I try to make a cron job running a .py-file.
The cron-job starts but I always get this error message "ImportError: No module named mysql.connector".

When I run exactly the same script via CLI, it runs smoothly. It connects to my db, it updates, inserts, ...  So, there is no issue with having this module (yes I installed).

So, how can I get this cron job to work?
This is how I start that job: python /home2/******/public_html/Test/cron_job_test.py
(when I run this via CLI it works)

Many thanks,
Peter

Comment: Are you installing the crontab for the same user as your CLI test?

Comment: It's on a hosting provider (Bluehost).
I have installed everything with the same username. CLI is run (via SSH) under the same username as the cron-job is run.
It starts the job but then errors it .

Comment: even if I put PYTHONPATH=/home2/***/python/python-3.6/site-packages python home2/******/public_html/Test/cron_job_test.py it doesn't work, still giving the same error message (no  module found) even the package is in there.
Version of python is  3.6.5

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying, I still wasn't able to get it working.
So time for an ugly bypass solution. Instead of a python script, I made a php script to do the work>
And run this cron job 'php /home2/******/public_html/Test/cron.php' and it works.

But I still want to know how to get the mysql.connector to work via crontab ;-)